# how does kubernetes' security work currently?

Tags: kubernetes

There's only some design docs here http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/design/README.html

can someone describe the details of kubernetes security workflow?

Comment: Kinda broad don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes does not have a complete authentication and authorization solution yet.  We are working on it.  If you can tell me more about your environment, I may be able to make tactical suggestions.  For example, are you on-prem or GKE? do you have existing internal web apps (not yet on kubernetes) and how to your internal users auth to those web apps?

Comment: I'm a little clear now, I use client certificate authentication between kubelet, kube-proxy, kube-controller-manager, kube-scheduler and kube-apiserver. and I use the default authorization mode to allow all request.

Answer (score 0):

The kubernetes security workflow is just like any application security workflow. If you're wondering about the options available for securing Kubernetes, a great place to start is by running `kubesec` on your pod.yaml file. [here is the website](https://kubesec.io/)

It will make security recommendations for you based on your pod configuration. Securing the pod is a great place to start because that's where attackers would land once they've compromised your application (think: damage control)

Comment: Please refer https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/security/